# Is this casino promotion exploitable?

Tags: probability, gambling

**The promotion is like this:**

Starting credit: 500 dollars

Maximum bet: 500 dollars

*Win up to 10000 dollars and get 10000 dollars free*.

House edge 52.5%.

Is this exploitable?

Comment: I don't think there is enough information here.

Comment: @karl i think it's something to do with the odds of winning 20 times your money while betting the same amount. i think the odds of winning 3 times your money is 33% - 2 times in a row = 25%, win once lose once and win twice = 6.25%, etc

Comment: What is the house edge defined as?  What do you mean get 100 dollar free? Is that 100 dollar  free bets? Do you keep gambling or are you stopping after a win or when you are up?

Comment: The casino has a 52.5% chance of winning while the player has 47.5%. The player has to use the 5 dollars to win up to 100 dollars in one sitting before he may stop if he wants to receive the "free" extra 100 dollars from the casino.

Comment: How do you get those figures? 20:1 seems like a high payout for a 47.5% chance of winning.

Comment: I'd include all this in the main question it will help responses.

Comment: the odds of winning 20 times in a row is something like 1/1000000. however there are other sequences that will add to the odds of winning up to 20 times the original amount. the odds of winning 2 times your money is 50%, and to win 3 times your money is 33%, 4 times about 16%. I doubt my numbers though.

Comment: Your first comment seemed to imply that if you won once you got 20 times your stake.

Comment: How much do you win each game for your 5 stake?

Comment: i apologize. i meant betting and winning 20x5 to reach the 100 dollar mark so that the player may withdraw an additional 100 dollars.

Comment: If you edit and include all your thoughts I'll up vote as the question is interesting. I still feel there is something missing though.

Comment: you win 5 dollars for every 5 dollars bet. but the odds of the player winning is 47.5%. I think one way to determine whether the promotion is to the player's advantage is the odds of a player being able to reach 100 dollars while only betting 5 dollars.

Comment: sorry i'm new to forums, I don't really know how to do this right yet.

Comment: A basic calculation is the expected winnings each game which is $0.475\times 5+0\times0.525$ in that sense not a good game as you expect to earn less than your stake.

Comment: No problems.  Effort is all that really counts.

Comment: i reach 4 times for around 25% and not 16%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will use the Gambler's ruin method to solve this problem.

The gambler stops playing after winning or getting ruined, whichever happens first.

Let $P(k)$ denote the probability that you lose all ýour money when your initial capital is $k \cdot \$500$.

$P(k) = pP(k+1) + qP(k-1), \:\: k = 1, 2, ... ,N-1 \:\:\:\: (*)$

where the total capital of you and the house is $\$10000$, i.e you need to win $\$9500$ from the house, and $10000/500 = N$, i.e. $N = 20$.

Rewriting $(*)$ we have

$P(k+1) - \frac{1}{p} P(k) + \frac{q}{p} P(k-1) = 0, \:\: k = 1, 2, ... ,N-1 \:\:\:\: (**)$

which is a second-order homogenous linear-coefficient difference equation.

Note that we also have

$P(0) = 1$ and $P(N) = 0$

So to find $P(k)$ reduces to solving $(**)$ subject to these boundary conditions.

Let $P(k) = r^k$, $(**)$ becomes

$r^{k+1}-\frac{1}{p}r^k + \frac{q}{p} r^{k-1} = 0, \:\:\: p + q = 1$

Setting $k=1$ we get a second order equation with solutions

$r_1 = 1$ and $r_2 = q/p$.

Then

$P(k) = c_1 + c_2(q/p)^k$

Using the boundary conditions

$P(0) = 1 \Rightarrow c_1 + c_2 = 1$

$P(N) = 0 \Rightarrow c_1 + c_2\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^N = 0$

Solving for $c_1$ and $c_2$, we obtain

$$c_1 = \frac{-(q/p)^N}{1-(q/p)^N}, \:\:\:\: c_2 = \frac{1}{1-(q/p)^N}$$

Hence

$$P(k) = \frac{(q/p)^k - (q/p)^N}{1-(q/p)^N}$$

---

In our case we are looking for $P(k)$, with $k = 1$, $N = 20$, $p=0.475$, $q =0.525$.

$$P(\text{lose the game}) = P(1) = \frac{(0.525/0.475)^1 - (0.525/0.475)^{20}}{1-(0.525/0.475)^{20}} = 0.9836$$

$$P(\text{win the game}) = 1 - P(\text{lose the game}) = 0.0164$$

---

Let $G$ be the random variable taking on values $\$19500$ if the gambler wins the game and $-\$500$ if the gambler loses the game.

The casino promotion is exploitable if the expected value of the game is greater than zero.

$$E[G] = 0.0164 \cdot \$19500 + 0.9836 \cdot (-\$500)= -\$172$$

Hence, not exploitable.

Comment: greatly appreciate your help. however is it possible to explain in simpler terms so that I'm able to explain it somehow to my boss? I hand drawn the total possible events on a piece of paper for winning 2x my original amt, then 3 then 4. the numbers i got are 50%, 33.33% and 25%. could you perhaps just tell me the odds of reaching 20 times my original amount? just trying to understand it myself as you can see I'm not very knowledgeable when it comes to numbers.

Comment: @user329161 I am using the Gambler's ruin method. Google and read more about it if you want to but what i am basically doing is calculating the probabilities for all routes the entire game can take ending in either you win or you lose. These probabilities "are added  up" so that the event that you lose consists of e.g. you lose the first bet and are finished, you win the first 18 bets then lose 19 bets in a row and are finished, etc , all those possible routes are included in $P(\text{lose})$ and similarly all possible routes that end in you getting to $\$10000$ are included in $P(\text{win})$

Comment: @user329161 When i did this i arrived at the result that it is a $98.36\%$ risk that you lose and a $1.64\%$ chance that you win. So if you were to play this game over and over again you would win $\$19500$ $1.64\%$ of the times and lose $\$500$ $98.36\%$ of the times. This means that you on average will lose $\$172$ each time. For the casino promotion to be exploitable you would have to win on average.

Comment: would there be a difference if the maximum limit is increased or even taken away to allow the player to bet as much as he wants?

Comment: @DANNY.OCEAN That is probably a much harder problem to solve. Let me think about it.

Answer (score 0):

I found this online **"Huygens' Result"**

[image]

According to the formula it would mean that the player's odds of success in reaching the 10000 dollars is around 5%.

I don't know the exact math but if the bonus given is 2000% and the player's odds of success is 5%, wouldn't that mean the bonus is exploitable even with the 2.5% house advantage?

Comment: You cant look at fair coin flipping. Look e.g. [Here 1](http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/FE-Notes/4700-07-Notes-GR.pdf) or [Here 2](http://www.cargalmathbooks.com/33%20Gambler's%20ruin%20.pdf) They arrive at the same result as i did. Note that its 1 - P that is the probability of ruin that i calculated.